# Looking for an element inside an array tells me parameter must be an object

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

When a user clicks a button, I am trying to see if that user already exists in an array before adding it, otherwise I don't want to add it to the existing array.

Here is the mongoose schema

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const productSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    category: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    image: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    userId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    requests: [
        {
             userId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true},
             firstName: {type: String},

        }
    ],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

and the query

```
exports.postRequest = (req, res, next) => {
    const productId = req.body.productId;
    const userId = req.body.userId;
    const firstName = req.body.firstName;
    Product.find({requests: userId})
    .then(product => {
      console.log(product);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  };
```

I thought that was all it took to look if a value exists inside of an array but I get an error:

> ObjectParameterError: Parameter "obj" to Document() must be an object

Comment: can u log the `userId` before `Product.find(..` ? is the parameter passed correctly ?

Comment: @bereketgebredingle, console gives me: 5d372b941676a10797b03e`1

Comment: Ok gud. Can u show us the `Product` schema ?

Comment: @bereketgebredingle, sure. Have updated my original question

Comment: @bereketgebredingle, thanks for that. But it gives me exactly the same error

Comment: May I hv your feedback on my answer post .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is showing u an error cause the requests is an array of objects. And u are querying to find the `userId` in the array. You should tell mongo which property to match with in the array of objects.

change it to this way

```
Product.find( { "requests.userId" : userId })
```

Comment: that gives me this: requests: [ [Object], [Object] ] } ]

Comment: I think it's actually right. It is because I am logging to console that I get that. If I JSON.stringify then I do get data back.